# Microsoft Access, vbYesNo can't get record to save

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Question on Access, I've created a vbYesNo on the save record button which asks me if is a new record, if it is a yes it saves as a new record, otherwise I need it to Update the existing record.

```
Private Sub btnSaveDetails_Click()

    Dim Response As Integer

    Response = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a new record?", vbYesNo, "Continue?")


    If IsNull(txtLocation) Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Location Details"
    Else
        If Response = vbYes Then
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
            Me.Refresh
            Me.cboSelectLocation = ""
            txtLocation.SetFocus
        Else
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The Problem basically is that on the Save button it asks if it is a new record, if it is a vbNo I need it to update the current record.

Comment: Please read all of these: [ask] --- [mcve] --- [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx). Then **edit** your question so it only contains relevant code, and a clear description of what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks, after reading I noticed it was a bit difficult to read

Comment: Replace Else
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
with
Else <update record code>

Comment: Since you use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`, this seems to be a bound form. Bound controls in a bound form *always* edit the current record (whether that's a new one or an existing one). You can't decide on saving to save the data to a different record than the current one. -- So you have to rethink your logic, I suggest to go with how Access works - if you want to create a new record, you *first* go there, then edit.

Comment: Ive solved it, just used a cancel = true and forced a save through the button only

Answer (score 0):

Different method to yours, but this is how I do mine:

```
If CloseResponse = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Suggestions_Historic SET [Status] = 'Closed By User', [ReasonClosed] = '" & ClosedWhy & "' WHERE ID = '" & ID & "'"
```